# trying to parse data from html with python but don't know how to proceed after getting table row element

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping

i'm trying to get data from the chiefs website and have them in python to manipulate with matplotlib. I can narrow it down to the table row but don't know how to proceed after that. I would love to have them on a row with (att, comp, yds, comp%, etc...) and then do a stdev and other math.

my code as of now regarding trying to get the data on a table.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.chiefs.com/team/stats/"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
rows
print(rows[:10])
```

i have all the information, but i don't know how to proceed.  [this is the numbers i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED4WH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas `read_html` function to get the tables. Note that it returns a list of dataframes so you will then have to decide which ones you want. Here it looks like t[0] is passing, t[1] is rushing, t[2] is receiving, etc.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
... url = 'https://www.chiefs.com/team/stats/'
... t = pd.read_html(url)

>>> len(t)
9

>>> t[0]

            Player  ATT  COMP   YDS   COMP%  YDS/ATT  TD   TD%  INT    INT%  LONG  SCK  SCK/LOST   RATE
0    Sammy Watkins    1     0     0    0.00      0.0   0  0.00    1  100.00   NaN    0         0    0.0
1   Tommy Townsend    1     1    13  100.00     13.0   0  0.00    0    0.00  13.0    0         0  118.8
2  Patrick Mahomes  588   390  4740   66.33      8.1  38  6.46    6    1.02  75.0   22       147  108.2
3     Travis Kelce    2     1     4   50.00      2.0   0  0.00    0    0.00   4.0    0         0   56.3
4       Chad Henne   38    28   248   73.68      6.5   2  5.26    0    0.00  37.0    2         4  108.2
```